# Use external javaScript library in angular 4 Component Library created with ng-packagr

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-packagr

With lots of help from this excellent article by Nikolas LeBlanc, I'm trying to create an Angular 4 component library:

https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

The problem is this... my library depends on an external JavaScript file - let's call that `somefunctions.js`.

In a regular Angular 4 application - I've been able to do this by referencing the file in the `angular-cli.json` file:

```
  "scripts": [
      "./app/js/somefunctions.js"
  ],
```

... then declare the variables as type `any` in the `typings.d.ts` file.

This makes the JavaScript file available to the ***application,*** and it works just fine.

However - my goal is to create an Angular 4 component library, and package/publish it to npm.

When I follow the instructions for creating the library - the feature module is packaged without `somefunctions.js`.

So - if someone else installs my module, they won't have `somefunctions.js`, and it obviously won't work.

So, I guess I need to know how to tell ng-packagr to bundle the module so that it includes `somefunctions.js`, and how to set up my module so that my code can reference that file when the module is installed in other applications.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anyone has solution for this? I am facing same issue too.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this issue? Please let me know if solved.